# Eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of fourth order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

Find the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of the problem
$$y^{(4)} − λy = 0$$

with the boundary conditions

(i)  $\quad y(0) = y'' (0) = y(β) = y'' (β) = 0$

(ii)  $\quad y(0) = y' (0) = y'' (β) = y''' (β) = 0$

(iii)  $\quad y(0) = y' (0) = y(β) = y' (β) = 0$

Comment: So far I haven't got anything

Comment: Have you even _tried_? If so, post what you have done and we will see where you're having trouble. If you're really struggling, heres a **hint**; Try an ansatz $y(t) = e^{\omega t}$.

Comment: I did try with the first BC and I get eigenvalues $\lambda = (\frac{n \pi}{\beta})^4$ and eigenfunction $\phi(x) = sin(\frac{n\pi x}{\beta})$

What about for the other B.C.'s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\bigg(\frac{d^{4}}{dt^{4}} - \lambda \bigg) y &= \bigg( \frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}} + \sqrt{\lambda} \bigg) \bigg(\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}} - \sqrt{\lambda} \bigg) y\\
&= \bigg(\frac{d}{dt} + i \lambda^{\frac{1}{4}} \bigg) \bigg(\frac{d}{dt} - i\lambda^{\frac{1}{4}} \bigg) \bigg(\frac{d}{dt} + \lambda^{\frac{1}{4}} \bigg) \bigg(\frac{d}{dt} - \lambda^{\frac{1}{4}} \bigg) y \\
&= 0
\end{align}$$

One of the solutions is given by

$$\begin{align}
\bigg(\frac{d}{dt} + i \lambda^{\frac{1}{4}} \bigg) y &= \frac{dy}{dt} + i \lambda^{\frac{1}{4}} y \\
&= 0 \\
\implies y_1(t) &= A\exp(-i\lambda^{\frac{1}{4}}t)
\end{align}$$

where $A$ is a constant. Now it remains to solve each of the other three ODEs (the bracketed terms above), $y_2, y_3, y_4$ to get your solution. Remember to add the solutions together for the total solution $y(t) = y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4$, then use your BCs to solve for the constants $A, B, C, D$.